# How to find the total number of keystrokes typed on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I was watching the Google I/O keynote. It was [mentioned that 60 billion words](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPtJd6AzU8c&feature=player_detailpage#t=314s) are typed on chrome everday.

Is the value updated locally and is there a way to access it? If not, is there any way to find the total number of keystrokes *I have typed*? Is there a 'safe' extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is definitely not updated locally. If Google Chrome in fact records all the users' keystrokes, then it is being sent directly to Google's servers and there is no way to access it.

It is possible that each keystroke is being sent to Google, to allow Chrome to display the auto-suggest results, for example.

[CNET article from 2008:](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13860_3-10031661-56.html)

> The auto-suggest feature of Google's new Chrome browser does more than
>   just help users get where they are going. It will also give Google a
>   wealth of information on what people are doing on the Internet besides
>   searching.
>
> Provided that users leave Chrome's auto-suggest feature on and have
>   Google as their default search provider, Google will have access to
>   any keystrokes that are typed into the browser's Omnibox, even before
>   a user hits enter.
>
> **What's more, Google has every intention of retaining some of that data
>   even after it provides the promised suggestions. A Google
>   representative told CNET News that the company plans to store about 2
>   percent of that data - and plans to store it along with the Internet
>   Protocol address of the computer that typed it.**
>
> **In theory, that means that if one were to type the address of a
>   site - even if they decide not to hit enter - they could leave
>   incriminating evidence on Google's servers.**

More info about keystorke logging in Google Chrome's auto-suggest [can be found here](http://www.zdnet.com/news/google-bows-to-keystroke-privacy-concerns/220444).

---

What you can do is use a keylogger extension and record the data yourself. Obviously, you need a safe keylogger for education purpose and not a malicious one.

I found some keylogger scripts which you can use:

- [Chrome Key Logger](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/73960)
- [Key Logger for Chrome for Facebook](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/102949)
- [Chrome Extension KeyLogger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/extensionkeylog/)
- [Facebook Keylogger 1.5.3 for Chrome Extension](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/73960) (seems outdated).

If they are outdated or they just don't work, you can always search for ["chrome keylogger script"](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=chrome%20keylogger%20script&oq=chrome%20keylogger%20script&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30.253.253.0.1181.1.1.0.0.0.0.327.327.3-1.1.0....0...1c..30.hp..0.1.327.UZ8B_PSBKDA) or ["chrome keylogger extension"](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=chrome%20keylogger%20extension&oq=chrome%20keylogger%20ex&gs_l=serp.1.0.0j0i22i30l2.52728.52994.0.53621.2.2.0.0.0.0.177.351.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.30.serp..0.2.351.BvVlje2UTbY).

They seem safe and simple (*Note: I haven't tested them*). Since they're chrome scripts (extensions) it's easy to work with and it only has access to Chrome so you should be able to get the data you need.

Some of them might work online with an internet connection, and some of them might work offline locally, so you probably need to know how to work with PHP and a SQL database.

After downloading the extension/script, open it (if it's a Chrome extension it's a `.crx` file). You should look for JavaScript files, for example:
`manifest.json` or `runtime.js` (this was the names in one of the extensions).

For website-specific scripts, like the Facebook one, you should change the script so it will work on every website in Chrome instead of just Facebook. Inside `manifest.json` (or other JS file), you need to edit the piece of code which currently triggers the keylogger only in `facebook.com` URLs, so it will run in any web page. So you need to [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2250163/1380370):

```
"matches": [ "https://www.facebook.com/*", "http://www.facebook.com/*", "http://*.facebook.com/*", "https://*.facebook.com/*"]
```

To:

```
"matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
```

And then drag the modified `.crx` extension file to `chrome://chrome/extensions/` and drop it there, so it will get installed.